# How to customize pcoGoDialog popup menu selection color in TcxPageControl?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, customization, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using Delphi 10.4 with DevExpress VCL components 2020.2.8. I want to customize `TcxPageControl`'s popup menu selection color. Example:

1. Create new Windows VCL Application - Delphi.
2. Drop a `TcxPageControl` on Form.
3. In `cxPageControl1.Options` set `pcoGoDialog` to `True`.
4. Add tabs until the "go dialog" dropdown button becomes visible.

   [image: "go dialog" button]
5. My code for customizing it:

   ```pascal
   unit Unit2;

   interface

   uses
     Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
     Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, dxBarBuiltInMenu, cxGraphics,
     cxControls, cxLookAndFeels, cxLookAndFeelPainters, dxSkinsCore, dxSkinBasic,
     cxPC, cxPCPainters, cxPCPaintersFactory;

   const
     MyStyleId = 100;

   type
     TForm2 = class(TForm)
       cxPageControl1: TcxPageControl;
       cxTabSheet1: TcxTabSheet;
       cxTabSheet2: TcxTabSheet;
       cxTabSheet3: TcxTabSheet;
       cxTabSheet4: TcxTabSheet;
       cxTabSheet5: TcxTabSheet;
       cxTabSheet6: TcxTabSheet;
       cxTabSheet7: TcxTabSheet;
       procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
       procedure cxPageControl1DrawTabEx(AControl: TcxCustomTabControl;
         ATab: TcxTab; Font: TFont);
     end;

     TMyPCPainter = class(TcxPCUltraFlatPainter)
     private
       class function GetStyleID: TcxPCStyleID; static;
     protected
       //function GetTabBodyColor(TabVisibleIndex: Integer): TColor; override;
       function GetTabsRowColor: TColor; override;
       function GetTabCorrection(ATabVisibleIndex: Integer): TRect; override;
       function GetButtonColor(AButtonState: TcxPCNavigatorButtonState): TColor; override;  public
     end;

   var
     Form2: TForm2;

   implementation

   {$R *.dfm}

   { TMyPCPainter }

   function TMyPCPainter.GetButtonColor(
     AButtonState: TcxPCNavigatorButtonState): TColor;
   begin
     Result:=clGray;
   end;

   class function TMyPCPainter.GetStyleID: TcxPCStyleID;
   begin
     Result := MyStyleId;
   end;

   function TMyPCPainter.GetTabCorrection(ATabVisibleIndex: Integer): TRect;
   begin
   // add space btn tabs
     Result := Rect(5, -1, 0,2);
   end;

   function TMyPCPainter.GetTabsRowColor: TColor;
   begin
     Result:=clGray;
   end;

   procedure TForm2.cxPageControl1DrawTabEx(AControl: TcxCustomTabControl;
     ATab: TcxTab; Font: TFont);
   begin
     if ATab.IsMainTab then begin
       ATab.Color := clWhite;
       Font.Color := clBlack;
     end
     else begin
       ATab.Color := clBlack;
       Font.Color := clWhite;
     end;
   end;

   procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     cxPageControl1.Style := MyStyleId;
     cxPageControl1.OnDrawTabEx:=cxPageControl1DrawTabEx;
   end;

   initialization
     RegisterPCPainterClass(TMyPCPainter);

   finalization
     UnregisterPCPainterClass(TMyPCPainter);

   end.
   ```
6. Run the application. Click on the "go dialog" drop down button. When you try to select a popup menu item it is highlighted in blue. Like shown in below picture:

   [image: go dialog's popup menu with blue selection color]

How to change the go dialog popup menu selection color?

Comment: Is this a [license](https://docs.devexpress.com/VCL/158018/ExpressPageControl/glossary/go-dialog) issue?

Comment: @AmigoJack  both Delphi and dev express are licensed.

Comment: The linked website mentions the "_ExpressBars Suite_".

Comment: @AmigoJack : in control panel , i didn't see any "ExpressBars Suit", but when i install devexpress for VCL it should install all the suits , right? FYI: i am not able to edit the "go dialog" at design time . i will try installing the DevExpress for VCL in new machine and i will try again. Thanks.

Comment: @AmigoJack : we can not customize the go dialog popup. i have asked the same question in dev express forum and they confirmed it. Work Around is create your own custom button and add a popup. :). Thank you.